# C# Constructor not being called

Tags: c#

I have a Selenium based Page Object Model which has a constructor. When I call the constructor, it is not called causing my test to fail. Below is my POM code and test code:

POM:

```
public class SellerLogin : PageObjectBase
{
    public SellerLogin(IWebDriver driver) : base(driver)
    {        
            WaitForElement(pageHeading);
    }

    public IWebElement pageHeading = ActionKeyword.GetElement(Driver, By.ClassName("login-title"));
    public IWebElement userName = ActionKeyword.GetElement(Driver, By.Id("UserName"));
    public IWebElement password = ActionKeyword.GetElement(Driver, By.Id("Password"));
    public IWebElement login = ActionKeyword.GetElement(Driver, By.XPath("//input[@value='Login']"));

    public override string PageUrl => "lxcheckout";

    public void Login(string UserName, string Password)
    {
        ActionKeyword.EnterText(userName, UserName);
        ActionKeyword.EnterText(password, Password);
        login.Click();
    }

}
```

Test:

```
[DataSource(dataSourceSettingName: "SellerCheckout")]
 [TestCategory("LisaXpress"), TestMethod]
 public void LisaXpress_SellerCheckout()
 {
      Test(() =>
      {
            var url = GetData("ApplicationUrl");
            LogInfo("Starting new test");
            Driver.Url = url;
            var a = new SellerLogin(Driver);
            a.Login("Electrical", "Password1");

       });
}
```

The constructor doesnt get called when I do the (when I debug the steps):

```
var a = new SellerLogin(Driver);
```

I am scratching my head on this. When I remove the reference to the base page class, the constrcutor is called. Any ideas?

Base constructor:

```
namespace Flexigroup_UI_Automation.Base
{
    public abstract class PageObjectBase
    {
        public abstract string PageUrl { get; }

        static int Timeout { get; set; }

        public static IWebDriver Driver { get; set; }

        protected PageObjectBase(IWebDriver driver)
        {
            Driver = driver;
            PageFactory.InitElements(Driver, this);
            Timeout = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Timeout (s)"] != null
                ? int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Timeout (s)"])
                : 10;
        }
```

Thanks,
Rahul Dixit

Comment: How have you proved to yourself (and us) it doesn't get called?

Comment: When I debug it jumps straight past the constructor to the rest of the POM. It doesnt do this when I remove the reference to the base class

Comment: @user1709356 It does not mean that constructor was not called.

Comment: well the base constructor sets a property called 'Driver', which is not set when i instantiate the object of the POM class. It is null causing a failed test.

Comment: @user1709356 It is strange that you have what looks like a type being passed: var a = new SellerLogin(Driver); What is "Driver"? Is that an instantiated instance of type IWebDriver?

Comment: yes it is an object of IWebDriver. The base POM has a another Driver property that is set to the passed in Driver. Since it is not set, because the constructor is not called, the test fails.

Comment: @user1709356 Can you show base class's constructor?

Comment: So, are you sure the base constructor doesn't throw?

Comment: Yes, it goes straight to getting the page locators, and the Driver is null.

Comment: What page locators are you talking about? Is your PageFactory.initElements working with a null object? If Driver is null, how can you assign the url to it in your test?

Comment: when i call the constructor it goes straight to:   public IWebElement pageHeading = ActionKeyword.GetElement(Driver, By.ClassName("login-title"));

Comment: @user1709356 - Still no [mcve]?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the constructor does get called.

```
void Main()
{
    var sl = new SellerLogin(new WebDriver());

    Console.WriteLine(SellerLogin.Driver != null);
}

public abstract class PageObjectBase
{
    public static IWebDriver Driver { get; set; }

    protected PageObjectBase(IWebDriver driver)
    {
        Driver = driver;
    }
}

public class SellerLogin : PageObjectBase
{
    public SellerLogin(IWebDriver driver) : base(driver) { }
}

public interface IWebDriver { }

public class WebDriver : IWebDriver { }
```

This prints `True` to the console.

You need to show us one where it doesn't get called.

Until we can copy paste and run your code **and see that the constructor doesn't get called** then you haven't got a complete question.